# Cannot unmarshal timestamps into *string

Tags: go, scylla

I am storing some timestamps in the scyllaDB and when retrieving it is showing error that **“Cannot unmarshal timestamps into *string”**
I am creating a todo API and when retrieving the todos from the DB it gives back the error: “Cannot unmarshal timestamps into *string”. The todo struct containing the createdAt and updatedAt fields are of type time.Time. Help me how to resolve this.
Here is the todo struct type:

```
type Todo struct {
    ID          gocql.UUID `json:"id"`
    UserID    string        `json:"user_id"`
    Title       string      `json:"title"`
    Description string      `json:"description"`
    Status      string      `json:"status"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time   `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time   `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

Here is the function:

```
func GetAllTodos(user_id string) ([]*Todo, error) {
    var todos []*Todo

    query := `SELECT * FROM todo WHERE user_id = ? ALLOW FILTERING`
    iter := Session.Query(query, user_id).Iter()

    var todo Todo
    for iter.Scan(&todo.ID, &todo.UserID, &todo.Title, &todo.Description, &todo.Status, &todo.CreatedAt, &todo.UpdatedAt) {      
        todos = append(todos, &todo)
        todo = Todo{}
    }

    if err := iter.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return todos, nil
}
```

Tried using different methods including creating separate variables for string or *string and parsing the timestamps using time.Parse or by directly passing it into the todo type struct or using  time.Unix functions by taking the timestamps returned in nanoseconds and converting into milliseconds: time.Unix(timeStr/1000,0)
Nothing have worked and the error continues to persist.

Comment: I suggest that you add the SQL schema of the table you are reading from. Showing an example row which can't be unmarshaled will help too.

Comment: From the information you provided it looks like the timestamps are not returned at the position you are expecting them to be returned. You expect them at the 2 last positions, but it seems they are not. Change `SELECT *` to `SELECT id, user_id, tittle, ...` and see if that solves it.

Comment: Also note, that the code will break if you add a new column in the table without updating the code at the same time. Using `SELECT *` is generally not a good idea.

Comment: One more comment: if `ALLOW FILTERING` is needed to perform a query, it basically does a full table scan. This will time out as soon as the table grows. Last company we worked with scylla and we had a strict "No ALLOW FILTERING"-rule.

Comment: a blind guess is: the columns in the query do not appear in the order you think they do. `SELECT

Comment: `Session.Query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, user_id text, title text, description text, status text, created_at timestamp, updated_at timestamp);").Exec()`
Here is the query used to create the table. @Fabian